# Django Rest Framework Price being returned to 1 decimal place

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework

When a price is e.g. 213.30 it is being returned as 213.3, not a huge problem but something that needs sorting, below is my Model and my Serializer. Have already tried looking online for more information but cant see anyone else having the same issue

"price": {
            "HighSell": 213.3
        }

My Model

```
class Product(models.Model):
    itemno = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    HighSell = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.itemno
```

My Serliazer

```
class ProdListSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    price = SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = [
            'id',
            'itemno',
            'price'
        ]

    def get_price(self, obj):
        customerNo = self._context['view'].request.query_params.get('customerNo', '')
        if customerNo:
            customerPrice = CustomerPrices.objects.filter(
                Q(customerNo=customerNo) &
                Q(itemno=obj.itemno)
            ).values('price').first()
            if customerPrice:
                return customerPrice
            else:
                return Product.objects.filter(itemno=obj.itemno).values('HighSell').first()
        else:
            return Product.objects.filter(itemno=obj.itemno).values('HighSell').first()
```

Comment: If you return your price as a number, the trailing zeros don't matter. They are only important when you display it, or if you save it as text. As it looks like you return it as a number, what would you expect to be different?

Answer (score 0):

The way you just displayed must work when it comes to the sorting, as the fields you are comparing are both of Decimal type.

If you just want to work on the representation of those fields through a serializer, I would recommend using the *[DecimalField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#decimalfield)* from Django Rest Framework's package serializers:

```
price = DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, coerce_to_string=True)
```

Thanks to the `coerce_to_string` function that returns strings instead of Decimal objects you will be able to achieve that desired behavior.